# how to migrate from paperclip to refile and to export/import the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, refile

I am trying to do something like a script to copy my files from the paperclip structure to refile structure. My files are stored on Amazon s3.

There is a way to make this?

My choose for the change is because i want to upload my files directly for amazon s3 for improve the performance of the uploads in my application and the refile makes this possible.